# Django multiple databases, does Django connect to all of them initially?

Tags: python, mysql, django

Sample database configuration for MySQL :

```
DATABASES = {
    'auth_db': {
        'NAME': 'auth_db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'swordfish',
    },
    'master': {
        'NAME': 'master',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'spam',
    },
    'slave1': {
        'NAME': 'slave1',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'eggs',
    },
    'slave2': {
        'NAME': 'slave2',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'bacon',
    },
}
```

Does Django connect to all of them initially, even if some of the databases are not used at all ?
eg.

Using raw cursors with multiple databases

> If you are using more than one database you can use
>   django.db.connections to obtain the connection (and cursor) for a
>   specific database. django.db.connections is a dictionary-like object
>   that allows you to retrieve a specific connection using its alias:
>
> from django.db import connections
>
> cursor =  connections['my_db_alias'].cursor()

So here,
 1.  the connections object contains already made connections ? Or does it connect when a request for cursor is made ?
 2. Is there a way to change this default behaviour and have the connections made on demand, ( All of the querying is as raw querying, and all databases are MySQL )   ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A persistent connection will be made to the requested database on the first access using `django.db.connections`.  That is, connections are lazily evaluated and connected only on first use.  The relevant code is in `django/db/__init__.py` in the `ConnectionHandler` class.

Connections are not automatically removed after a query however, the connection will remain until disconnected.  If there are entries in `DATABASES` which are never used, no connection will be made to these databases.

Answer (score -1):

Django uses the database with the alias of default when no other database has been selected. If you don’t have a default database, you need to be careful to always specify the database that you want to use. In your case, you don't need a default or a auth_db for user auth etc?

In any case, connections should be on-demand , you could connect to the MYSQL Explorer and issue the following command to see the active connections and then request a cursor and check the result of the command again and compare. The command is as below...

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html

Please report back your findings.

Comment: This is the question reframed IMHO :(

Comment: Checking the current open connections would be the best and sure-shot way to arrive at your answer Dhruv.